# Need help regarding the new Lightning flow builder (lookup field)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lookup, visual-workflow

so as the title says I'm trying to populate a lookup filter when inserting a record using a Flow, I already created the lightning component to serve as a Lookup field and I was able to show it on the Screen and it worked, the only thing that I'm missing is that the value that I put is not being saved after the record is inserted. Tell me if you need some more input from me. I just want to understand a way to store the Component value on this new Flow Builder

Bellow, I will put some images with what I've done.

[image: Screen Flow]

[image: Part of the flow that matters]

[image]
Ty for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this:

1. Your Lightning component needs to have an attribute that stores the value from the input field.
2. In Flow Builder, under Stored Output Values, you need to store the result from that attribute in a resource variable - similar to how you have configured the Default field in your screenshot. Then you can reference that variable in your other elements.

You might want to take a look at this sample lookup field: https://github.com/alexed1/LightningFlowComponents/tree/master/flow_screen_components/lookupFSC/force-app/main/default/aura/lookupFSC

PS: in future, please paste your actual code - not a screenshot - in your questions. It's really hard to read in an image.